# laravel 7 adding radio in register form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, radio-button

i want to add radio in register form. For when someone want to register he need to choice if its man or woman and when i try to register its not work dont save in database 
Someone can helping me add the radio for choice man or woman.

create user table :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
           $table->string('firstname');
           $table->string('email')->unique();
           $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
           $table->string('password');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->date('created_at');
           $table->string('address');
           $table->string('city');
           $table->string('zipcode');
           $table->string('gender');
           $table->string('number')->unique();
           $table->date('birthday');
           $table->string('pseudo')->unique();
           $table->rememberToken();
       });
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists('users');
       $table->dropColumn('gender');
   }
}
```

user.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'birthday', 'email', 'password', 'firstname', 'address', 'city', 'zipcode', 'gender', 'number', 'pseudo',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Register controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'zipcode' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'birthday' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:today'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'pseudo' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'unique:users'],
            'number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'unique:users'],
            'gender' => ['required', 'string'],

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'number' => $data['number'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'pseudo' => $data['pseudo'],

            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

register blade php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Firstname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>

                                @error('firstname')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autocomplete="address" autofocus>

                                @error('address')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="city" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('city') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control @error('city') is-invalid @enderror" name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" required autocomplete="city" autofocus>

                                @error('city')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="zipcode" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('zipcode') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="zipcode" type="text" class="form-control @error('zipcode') is-invalid @enderror" name="zipcode" value="{{ old('zipcode') }}" required autocomplete="zipcode" autofocus>

                                @error('zipcode')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="number" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('number') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="number" type="text" class="form-control @error('number') is-invalid @enderror" name="number" value="{{ old('number') }}" required autocomplete="number" autofocus>

                                @error('number')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="birthday" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('birthday') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date" class="form-control @error('birthday') is-invalid @enderror" name="birthday" value="{{ old('birthday') }}" required autocomplete="birthday" autofocus>

                                @error('birthday')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div id="gender-group" class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Gender') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div><input id="female" type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="Female"> {{ (old('sex') == 'female') ? 'checked' : '' }} >Female</div>
                                    <div><input id="male" type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="Male"> {{ (old('sex') == 'male') ? 'checked' : '' }} >Male</div>
                                    @error('gender')
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Someone can talk where is my error ?

Comment: You had a typo in your creat method.

Comment: typo? what is it typo?

Comment: Typo means you are spelling something wrong, in your create method, change gendre to gender

Comment: thanks for info =) but it's not work :/ when i click in register nothing happened. i share register blade.php i think error something there but i dont know where...

Answer (score 3):

Migration:

```
...
    $table->boolean('gender')
        ->default(1)
        ->comment('Gender');
...
```

Model:

```
...
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'gender' <--- required !
    ...
];

protected $casts = [
    ...
    'gender' => 'boolean'
    ...
];
...
```

View:

```
{{ Form::radio('gender', 1, old('gender'), ['id' => 'gender-man']) }}
{{ Form::label('gender-man', 'Man') }}

{{ Form::radio('gender', 0, old('gender'), ['id' => 'gender-female']) }}
{{ Form::label('gender-female', 'Woman') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, you store gender as integer. However, in the frontend, you pass the gender as string. Did you convert the gender to integer?

Comment: Ok thanks, i was update but not changing :/ nothing happened...

Comment: So what you're saying is: you convert the gender to integer, and it's still not updating?

Comment: No, i write gender in string. and no have update or something and it's not save in database

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an enum type for the gender column in your migration file. This enforces the gender value to be either 'Male' or 'Female', which can be more efficient and reliable.

Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ... other columns ...
        $table->enum('gender', ['Male', 'Female']);
        // ... other columns ...
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('gender');
    });
}
```

register.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div><input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female</div>
    <div><input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male</div>
</div>
```